# Take first three letters in the string

Tags: scala, list

I need to retrieve first three letters

```
val s ="abc"
val t = s.substring(0,2).equals("ab")
case class Test(id :String)

if(t){
  Test("found")
 }else{
   None
 }
```

Is there a efficient way to code for the above logic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
"abc".take(2) match {
  case "ab" => Test("found")
  case _ => None
}
```

for `String`, you can use `take` to get chars like `Seq`, and it's more safe than `substring` to avoid `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

and since you are returning `None` when not match, `Test("found")` Shouldn't be `Some(Test("found"))`?

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
case class Test(id: String)
val s = "abc"

if (s.take(2) == "ab") Test("found") else None
```

Make sure your string is at least 2 characters long or `take` will throw an exception.

Comment: `take` does not throw. It just returns whatever there is to return: `math.min(math.max(until, 0), length)` (that is scala 2.12.8)